# Upload video to facebook using graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-apps

I am using the following code for uploading videos to users wall:

```php
if( isset($_POST['submitVideo']) ) {
   $img =  $_FILES['source']['name'];     
   $ret_obj = $facebook->api('/me/videos', 'POST', array(
      'source' => '@' . $img,
      'title' => "This is just a test",
      'description' => 'test9000',
      'privacy' => json_encode(array( 'value' => 'EVERYONE' )),
      )
   );
   echo '<pre>Video ID: ' . $ret_obj['id'] . '</pre>';
}
```

the Form looks like this:

```html
<form target="uploadTarget" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
   <input name="source" type="file">
   <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="submitVideo" />
</form>
```

My problem is with the source of the images. Is it correct to use this:

```php
$img =  $_FILES['source']['name'];
```

what should be the source? I am uploading the file from my local computer. 
**EDITED:**
What if I use the following pattern for same form and use this "$post_url" as action:

```php
$post_url = "https://graph-video.facebook.com/me/videos?"
        . "title=" . $video_title. "&description=" . $video_desc
        . "&access_token=". $access_token;
```

It works. but goes to this "$post_url" page where it shows the ID of the uploaded file. How can I use that ID to put into my Database?

Answer (score 0):

> is it correct to use this:
>
> ```
> $img =  $_FILES['source']['name'];
> ```

No, as http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php tells you, this is *“The original name of the file on the client machine.”* – which is of course not what you want.

You want to use the name of the file that gets stored temporarily on your server after it has been uploaded to your server by the client:

> $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']
>
> The temporary filename of the file in which the uploaded file was stored on the server.

---

If this does not work (f.e. the temporary directory for file uploads might not be accessible to cURL [which the PHP SDK uses internally] directly), the you will have to use `move_uploaded_file` first to store the file in another location on your server.